# Trying to establish a connection between android application and localhost

Tags: android

Hi I'm using android studios and I'm trying to connect my android phone to my webserver, I can connect fine through my webbrowser but I have no success connecting through my phone:

Here's my code to connect through my android application:

```
            URL url = new URL("http://raspberrypi/test.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

My log currently outputs the following:

```
04-13 05:07:53.770 19471-19471/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

04-13 05:07:53.770 19471-19471/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:19471

04-13 05:07:53.870 19471-19471/com.example.albert.superlyduperdoorsystem E/Typeface: SANS_LOC file not found.

04-13 05:07:54.300 19471-19471/com.example.albert.superlyduperdoorsystem D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 11(0x72617370626572),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4

04-13 05:07:54.300 19471-19471/com.example.albert.superlyduperdoorsystem D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, err=8

04-13 05:07:54.390 19471-19471/com.example.albert.superlyduperdoorsystem D/Atlas: Validating map...
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: use emulator to run your application

Comment: what error exactly you are facing...post your logcat here

Comment: I agree with Vishal, please attach your log and make the problem clear, describe the expected result.

Comment: Whats your concrete trouble?

Comment: Ideally the code should load the site which will then trigger a python code to light an led, the problem is I can't seem to connect to the webserver

Comment: @someguyal As you said you are trying to connect your device to local host. one more thing I want to know that in phone your using mobile data internet or some wifi..?

Comment: On the mobile phone I am connected to the same router that the webserver is connected to.

Comment: ok...Once try to run your application on another phone.

Comment: Try with a browser on your phone.

Comment: What is `raspberry` ? Better use an ip address.

Comment: What has this to do with `localhost` ?